# How to add Loginout to Sub-menu

Tags: menus, login, logout

I've been searching all over the interwebs for this one. I've got the code snippets to add Loginout to a menu as a main menu item. I'm now looking to understand how to attach it to a sub-menu. This is what I have so far:

```
function wti_loginout_menu_link( $items, $args ) {
   if ($args->theme_location == 'secondary-menu') {
      if (is_user_logged_in()) {
         $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">'. __("Log Out") .'</a></li>';
      } else {
         $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_login_url(get_permalink()) .'">'. __("Log In") .'</a></li>';
      }
   }
   return $items;
}
```

How do I get it from the top level to the sub-menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a sub menu to an existing navigation menu in WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254321/how-can-i-add-a-sub-menu-to-an-existing-navigation-menu-in-wordpress)

Comment: I'd seen that one, but assumed that as it was for plugins/admin menu it wouldn't be applicable to general menu items. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you take a look in [wp_nav_menu_objects](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_objects/) documentation you'll see that it applies to all navigation menus. Please, write some code and try it for yourself. If you still have questions, update here with the new code.

Comment: Thanks for that. The only bit I'm not entirely sure about with that answer is what the section `$results = 'SOME SQL QUERY'; ` means? Do I need that? I'm having to declare the loginout in my functions.php anyway, so how do I incorporate that into the linked answer?

Comment: What's the generated HTML code of your menu with submenu items?